# Contract.ForAll doesn't work?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I'm trying to use `Contract.ForAll`, and it looks like I'm missing something here.

Consider this small example:

```
        var l = new List<string>();
        Contract.Assume( Contract.ForAll( l, s => s != null ) );

        foreach ( var s in l ) Console.WriteLine( s.Length );
```

Despite the `Contract.Assume` call, I do get a "*possible calling a method on a null reference*" warning for `s.Length`.

Am I doing this right? Is it even supposed to work? Or am I missing something?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679395/codecontracts-possibly-calling-a-method-on-a-null-reference

Comment: @Robert: I don't quite understand what that question has to do with mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Code Contracts User Manual](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/2/7/C2715F76-F56C-4D37-9231-EF8076B7EC13/userdoc.pdf), section 6.6.1 Current Limitations of the Checker and Bugs:

> The static contract checker does not yet deal with quantifiers ForAll or Exists.

Comment: Well, that was my first thought, but I found the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104856/using-contract-forall-in-code-contracts. The first comment to the original post indicates that the latest version should work ok.

Comment: Interesting... I wish he had provided a source!  That comment is from July 9th, and the latest copy of the user manual is dated September 3rd.  Not sure who to believe, but I am leaning towards the documentation.

Comment: I did some searching and found [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/94ec2bce-61b5-463c-a1b6-22c22a42e67f) from April 2009 indicating the static checker did not support Contract.ForAll, but that MS hoped to support it by the end of summer 2009.  Then [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/20e80553-98ce-4771-8bb7-143816af3ded) from January 2010 asking about it with a response from MS that it still wasn't working.  Responses to that post from a month ago indicate that it is still not supported.

Comment: Ok then, I guess I'll just have to wait... Thanks :-)

Comment: It's enabled but not fully completed. See the other answer :)